# plt.imshow() not showing numpy matrix correctly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

I'm having trouble drawing a rectangle on an image with OpenCV, and then displaying the image with matplotlib.  This code in a Jupyter Notebook results in a black image being displayed, with no green rectangle:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

%matplotlib inline
image = np.zeros((720, 1280, 3))
cv2.rectangle(image, (100,100), (200,200), color=(0,255,0), thickness=2) # Green
plt.imshow(image)
```

I believe I can see the rectangle if I display the image with `cv2.imshow()`, but I don't know that OpenCV images can be displayed inline in Jupyter Notebooks like matplotlib images can.

EDIT: I think what's really going on is explained in this excerpt from [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

> The value for each component of MxNx3 and MxNx4 float arrays should be
>   in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

It can handle values between 0 and 255 if it's an integer array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default when you create a numpy array using `np.zeros()` or `np.ones()`, the default data type of the matrix is set to be float, or more precisely `np.float64`, And there seems to be some problem in matplotlib to render a matrix with float data type (As per convention the RGB values in an image are always integral, so we can't blame matplotlib for this.)

Now you have 2 options:

- Create the numpy matrix with `np.uint8` datatype

  ```
  image = np.zeros((720, 1280, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
  ```
- Convert the matrix in integral type before rendering it on plt.

  ```
  image = np.astype(image, np.uint8)
  ```

Also you need to add `plt.show()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks.  By the way, I omit `plt.show()` because I'm in a Jupyter Notebook, and the image appears even without calling that function.  Outside of a Jupyter Notebook, I do indeed need that function call.

Comment: Oh, it's fine then :)